# Remove space between bars of Google histogram chart in Angular

Tags: angular, histogram, angular-google-chart

I am using google histogram chart in my angular application, But i am unable to remove the space between the bars.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the bar.groupWidth to 100%. Following image is from the documentation. You can either specify the width using percentage or pixels.

[image]

```
   bar: {
        groupWidth: '100%'
    }


chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pnf09oj/)

Comment: I have already tried with that and it's not working for me.  protected options = {
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    colors: ['steelblue'],
    bar: {groupWidth: '100%'},
    backgroundColor: {strokeWidth:2,stroke:'#666'},
    isStacked: true,
    histogram: {
      lastBucketPercentile: 2,,
      bucketSize: 1,
      maxNumBuckets: 400,
      hideBucketItems: true
    },
   seriesType: 'bars',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Cycle Time (In hours)',
    },
    vAxis: { title: 'Order Frequency'},
  }

Comment: Can you check the chart.draw() function does it look like this?? If not change it  
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));